# Mysql Data copy

Tags: mysql

I want to copy the whole Mysql Data including Events to newly Os installed system.is it possible to do that? Note: I have have copied the Data folder it works fine except Events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the data files on to another machine where you've installed the same version of MySQL as was previously used and mysqldump --events them from there. Make sure this includes the "mysql" system database. Note that it has to be the SAME version. You can throw this instance away when finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) with the `--events` option

Comment: I can not use Mysqldump as the machine have the Data only and mysql service has been removed.